# Properties of loops under lifting

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $p \colon (\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_0) \to (X,x_0) $ be a covering space. Is it always true that if the image of a path $\tilde{\gamma}$ under $p_*$ is a loop $\gamma$ based at $x_0$, then $\tilde{\gamma}$ is a loop based at $\tilde{x}_0$? Do we have to make connectivity assumptions about the spaces $X$ and $\tilde{X}$?

Comment: First question: No, very much not. Try to work with any nontrivial covering space for an example, eg $\Bbb R \to S^1$.

Comment: Coveringness doesn't even enter into it. This is false as soon as $p^{-1}(x_0)$ contains at least one point other than $\bar{x}_0$ in the same path component.